# Angular 2 Host Event Listener bubbling

Tags: angular

I have built a directive which subscribes the keyboard event using host event listener. When escape key is pressed I am firing an output event like this

```js
    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(kbdEvent: KeyboardEvent) {
       if (kbdEvent.keyCode === 27) {
            this.CloseEvent.emit();
       }
    }
```

I have this directive for child elements. When escape key is pressed I want to fire the output event only for the newly subscribed elements. The problem is when I click on escape key the event is fired based on hierarchical order. I have made a demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/FfnHAtxl2zcHsu0JilKt

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add Multiple Child Elements
2. Click On <kbd>Escape</kbd> it closes all elements

Expected behavior:

1. When <kbd>Escape</kbd> is clicked on the last added child element, the event needs to be fired

Comment: since you're doing this `'document:keyup'` every instance of the directive will add a global event listener for keyup, so no matter where you press a key it will emit on all instances of the directive. See the console here https://plnkr.co/edit/9paiFapxVf2yaB6uPAnc?p=preview

Comment: you are correct.is there any way i can fire the recently added subscribed instance first and stop event propagation so that it avoids the other instances to stop firing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be listening to the `keyup` event of the rendereing element.

```
@HostListener('keyup') onKeyup() {
     this.defaultColor.emit('');
 }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/i2VikFSbIVWXtPwQqsqt?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an event listener to `document:keyup`.

> The Document interface represents any web page loaded in the browser.

Try `@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])` to subscribe to the `keyup` event of the DOM element that hosts the attribute directive.

Comment: thank you for the reply.Does this keyup fire only if i focus on the element which has subscribed

Comment: @abhilashreddy Yes. This is the updated Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/IQgwhySCDzyrELGCQXcS?p=preview